# How to overlap one element over another

Tags: html, css

Hi i have an `<hr>` line stretching across the page, but I think it keeps getting cut off by an image above it.  Does anyone know how I could make it so that the `<hr>` line overlaps the image?

```
<img src=".\pncwelcome.png" 
    style="float:right; clear:right; margin-top:-40px;" 
    alt="PNC Welcome Logo"/>
<hr color="black" 
    style="margin-top:30px;" />
```

Comment: this is a snippet of the code.  It is not off the page..

Comment: Running your snippet in jfiddle it looks fine. Can you provide an example that reproduces the error? http://jsfiddle.net/p5PBn/

Answer (score 5):

Use `position: absolute;`.

[Check the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ttRCm/)

Something like this should work.

The CSS:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
}

hr {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <hr>
    <img src="http://fanumusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Free.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Z-index. In the css if you set the hr to a higher z-index value it will be layered over the image. Or since you're floating the image, float the hr too and then set a higher z-index 
on it so that it will still overlap the image.

If you float the `<hr>` you will have to set a width on the parent element.

Use:

```
<img src=".\pncwelcome.png" style="z-index: 1; float:right; clear:right; margin-top:-40px;" alt="PNC Welcome Logo"/>
<hr color="black" style="z-index: 2; margin-top:30px;" />
```

If that doesnt' solve it use this instead:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" style="float:right; clear:right; margin-top:-40px; z-index:1;" alt="PNC Welcome Logo"/>
<hr color="black" style="float: left; z-index: 2; margin-top:-30px; width: 100%;" />
```

Comment: what would that look like?

Comment: Let me check with my partner.  One moment

Comment: your suggestion does not seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/TSCeS/ Also  if you add `position:relative;` which is required for the z-index to work. Not sure why though...

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Savas's answer, as I experienced some rendering issues when the `<img>` was not also given absolute positioning...

Here is how one would create an `<hr>` with a graphical embellishment.  The `<div>` is sized to the graphic being used and everything is treated like a single, spatially-defined unit on the page:

```
#example {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 92px;
}

#example hr {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 46px;
    bottom: 46px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #8fcbf1;
}

#example img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 272px;
    height: 92px;
    z-index: 5;
    left: calc(50% - 136px);
}
```

```
<div id="example">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google" />
  <hr />
</div>
```

Here is the Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/z517fkjx/

Also, this uses `calc()` for centering, which is CSS3-only.